# Is there any way to target some data in same class using CSS?

Tags: css, jsp, struts

```
<p class="side_menu_heading_color">
                        <s:property value="#session.scorerInfo.roleDescription" /><br>
                        <s:property value="#session.scorerInfo.scorerId" /><br/> // This property need to be targeted
```

Here I want to target second property using CSS. I am using the same code in all the JSP pages. And don't want modify JSP side code

Comment: try using the :nth-child selector

Comment: @TimGerhard it's not working I tried too. Thanks for the information.

Comment: is the <p> tag closing after the last property? the nth-child selector only works if all elements (encapsulated in your p-tag) are of the same type. Also: I'm not familiar with jsp but what html element will be rendered if you use "<s:property>"? is it a div? or a span?

Comment: @TimGerhard yes it closes after the last property but it is not a good idea for future use if someone adds new property in this div. I want to make it dynamic. Do you know how to add CSS class in the specific property?

Comment: i think you can use a cssClass or styleClass (not sure, since I usually don't work with jsp).

Comment: @TimGerhard yes I tried to but getting this error Attribute cssClass invalid for tag property according to TLD

Comment: I'd just wrapp it in a <div> or <span> then and apply the class to this element

Comment: @TimGerhard yes it works but UI gets disturbed Thanks buddy

Comment: yeah I know, you'll probably have to change your css styles etc

Comment: @TimGerhard yes I will do that. Thanks for your time.